# Why is semaphore needed if we are synchronizing the function anyway

Tags: java, multithreading

The below code i took from oracle docs on Semaphore.

My question is, if i am synchronizing the getNextAvailableItem() and  markAsUnused methods anyway which will stops other 99 threads to enter in the main function which either give me shared resource or accepts it back.Then what is the use of semaphore as that it does not matter whether it is 99 or 1000 threads which are waiting for the lock.

```
 class Pool {
    private static final int MAX_AVAILABLE = 100;
    private final Semaphore available = new Semaphore(MAX_AVAILABLE, true);

    public Object getItem() throws InterruptedException {
      available.acquire();
      return getNextAvailableItem();
    }

    public void putItem(Object x) {
       if (markAsUnused(x))
         available.release();
    }

    // Not a particularly efficient data structure; just for demo

    protected Object[] items = ... whatever kinds of items being managed
    protected boolean[] used = new boolean[MAX_AVAILABLE];

    protected synchronized Object getNextAvailableItem() {
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_AVAILABLE; ++i) {
        if (!used[i]) {
           used[i] = true;
           return items[i];
       }
      }
      return null; 
    }
       protected synchronized boolean markAsUnused(Object item) {

           for (int i = 0; i < MAX_AVAILABLE; ++i) {
           if (item == items[i]) {
           if (used[i]) {
            used[i] = false;
             return true;
           } else
             return false;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is: do you want the threads to block until there is an item available?

If yes, then semaphore is necessary as it's basically a counter that blocks when it's already zero and a thread is trying to acquire it.

Clearly you could try to implement this yourself inside the synchronized method without the semaphore (i.e. using some low level constructs like `wait`/`notify`) but that's just an invitation for hard-to-find bugs.

If blocking isn't necessary and you're cool with the method returning null to the caller, then you can skip the semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

The question to ask is, what if item is not available when `getItem` is called. And clearly the requirement here is to wait until one is available. Using just `synchronized` alone will not work, since it will not allow waiting in unlocked state (and waiting in a locked state would prevent anybody from releasing anything).

A counting semaphore is the most efficient way to implement this. When your `available.acquire();` returns successfully (ie. doesn't throw `InterruptedException`), it is *known* that at least one of the items is available (because item count matches semaphore's initial count, and count of free items is kept in sync with semaphores counter).

There are alternatives, but they are not as good.

You could use a mutex and a condition variable, called [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) and [`Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) in Java (or you could use Java's `wait` and `notify` too, together with `synchronized`). The `getItem` would have a loop: lock the mutex, see if item is avaiable: if it is, take it and return, else wait for condition variable and try again. And then `putItem`would signal the condition variable after releasing an item, which would wake up any waiters, so they know to check for availability. But this is a bit more code, potentially a bit less efficient (especially if *all* waiters are woken up instead of just one), and also Java `Condition` does not provide a way to have fair queuing, while `Semaphore` has the *fairness* boolean property, so waiters are served in order.

Then a really much worse alternative would be to have just a `Lock` or a `synchronized` block, then in a loop check if item is available and take it if possible, otherwise (optionally) sleep a bit, then try again. But this is inefficient, ugly, does not scale to many threads, and will make any experienced developer cringe.

Comment: Hi hyde..Thanks for response.I have seen in one more tutorial..synchronized being used with semaphore and as i am a beginner in java,I want to understand what is the significance it has here as we are locking the class on a mutex lock of the object and that will not let any thread to get it.So what i feel  there is no need of counting semaphore here and one more thing if you could suggest me some good book which could explain me these small things in details i will be very thank full to you

Comment: I just added new 1st paragraph. To summarize, problem is waiting for item to become available, without blocking other threads from releasing an item.